# SwiftUI list view with GroupedListStyle and horizontalSizeClass regular breaks on iOS 13.5 when turned to landscape mode

Tags: ios, swiftui

Looks like iOS 13.5 introduced a new bug, this is not reproducible in iOS 13.3.
When using the following code and turn to landscape mode with **device that has notch**, the text inside the list gets cut off. Does anyone have any workaround or fix? Filed a bug report to Apple.

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        Text("Some Text")
    }
    .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
    .environment(\.horizontalSizeClass, .regular)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is reproducible on a real device or just the simulator? As some bugs are simulator only.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on real device and Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in Xcode 12 and iOS 14. #FB7744163